# Partial or ordinary derivative of $g(x(t),y(t),z(t))$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If I have a function $f(x,y,z)=3x^2y$ I have the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial x}=6xy$, $\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial y}=3x^2$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial z}=0$

But suppose I have a function $g$ where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are functions of $t$, i.e. $g(x(t),y(t),z(t))=3x(t)^2y(t)$. How is the derivatives now defined?  Should I use the partial or ordinary derivative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you need the chain rule for vector valued functions (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions). To apply it, define a new function $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ by $h(t)=(x(t),y(t),z(t))$. Then $g(x(t),y(t),z(t))=g(h(t))$. If you apply the chain rule now, you obtain
$$\frac{d}{dt}(g(h(t)))=x'(t)\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}(x(t),y(t),z(t)) + y'(t)\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}(x(t),y(t),z(t))+z'(t)\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}(x(t),y(t),z(t)).$$